# Independence of a convergent series of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, independence, time-series

Suppose $\{\epsilon_n  \vert n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is an i.i.d. collection of $L_2$ random variables and $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \vert \varphi_i\vert < \infty $ such that the time series $ \sum_{i=0}^\infty \varphi_i \epsilon_{n-i} $ converges almost surely and in $L_2$ for every $n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Is it true that $\epsilon_{n+1}$ is independent of $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \varphi_i \epsilon_{n-i} $?

Comment: Are the $\phi_i$ random variables, too?

Comment: No, just real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Since the $\epsilon_k$ are iid, any function of $\{\epsilon_k:k\in A\}$ is independent of any function of $\{\epsilon_k : k\in B\}$, when $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $\mathbb Z$.  That is, the two  sigma field generated the two sets of variables are independent.  In your case, consider $A=\{n+1\}$ and $B=\{n-i:i\ge 0\}$.